# Does systemd support on-failure restarts for forking daemons?

Tags: linux, daemon, systemd

Assume I have the following in my systemd unit file:

```
Type=forking
Restart=on-failure
```

Parent process exits with status 0 (child launched successfully).  At some later point, the child dies with a non-zero status.  What happens?  systemd can track the child daemon process PID:

```
Process: 1768 ExecStart=/bin/mydaemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 1770 (mydaemon)
```

Is "Restart=on-failure" only looking at the parent exit status, or also the child?

Comment: I think it should work as expected and restart the daemon. Do you have any reason to believe it does not? Or are you looking for documentation of this behaviour?

Comment: @rodrigo--It's not well documented either way and I've got limited capability to test without affecting a production service.  A doc pointer would be great!

Comment: @jww, appreciate the heads up.  I will take this to a more appropriate venue.

Comment: It's not well documented anywhere. It's implied by virtue of tracking the child process with either `GuessPID` (default when `PIDFile` is empty) or `PIDFile`.

Comment: @MatthewLeonhardt - I find [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) is very good for systemd questions. I've asked several systemd questions there.

Comment: Here's the text from systemd service _If set to forking, it is expected that the process configured with ExecStart= will call fork() as part of its start-up. The parent process is expected to exit when start-up is complete and all communication channels are set up. **The child continues to run as the main daemon process**. This is the behavior of traditional UNIX daemons. If this setting is used, it is recommended to also use the PIDFile= option, so that systemd can identify the main process of the daemon. systemd will proceed with starting follow-up units as soon as the parent process exits._

Comment: And finally, _GuessMainPID=
Takes a boolean value that specifies whether systemd should try to guess the main PID of a service if it cannot be determined reliably. This option is ignored unless Type=forking is set and PIDFile= is unset because for the other types or with an explicitly configured PID file, the main PID is always known. The guessing algorithm might come to incorrect conclusions if a daemon consists of more than one process. **If the main PID cannot be determined, failure detection and automatic restarting of a service will not work reliably**. Defaults to yes._

Comment: @alvits.  Yes, I'm using GuessPID (which is working fine in lieu of my daemon keeping a pidfile).

Comment: Then I'd expect it to work because systemd is able to guess the main pid.

Comment: @jww I asked over there, but it sounds like it should behave as I expect.  I'm nervous about making the change in the absence of clear documentation and controlled testing.  Thanks for everyone's feedback.

Comment: @Matt - No problems... If its any consolation, I suffer systemd over at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). My laste several questions there have been about unexpected behavior due to systemd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes, it works as one would expect.

Full answer thanks to @thecarpy over on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377530/does-systemd-support-on-failure-restarts-for-forking-daemons.